# Console Application exception

Tags: c#

upon the requirement of our senior, we were asked to create an application where the user enters and gets details of his/her Savings information...

its working perfectly fine,
except the fact that when i press Enter key, i get an exception and my program crashes..

please provide me information so that in my console application, even if i press Enter key, i dont get exception, instead, it returns the program.

thanks much , 
help very much appreciated.

this is my program.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;



namespace bankprob {



    class sav_acc

    {

        public float amount;

        public sav_acc(float amount)
        {

            this.amount = amount;

        }

        public void getdeposit(float depos)
        {

            amount += depos;

        }

        public void display()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Balance of Customer :{0} ", amount);

        }


        public void withdrawl(float amt)
        {

            amount =amount - amt;

        }

        public void minbal()
        {

            if (amount < 1000)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("You cannot withdraw beyond the minimum balance of rupees 1000. ");
                return;
            }

        }

    }

    class cur_acc 
    {

        public float amount = 0;

        public cur_acc( float amount)


        {

            this.amount = amount;

        }

        public void getdeposit(float depos)
        {

            amount += depos;

        }

        public void display()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Balance of Customer : {0}", amount);

        }


        public void withdrawl(float amt)
        {

            amount = amount - amt;

        }

        public void minbal()
        {

            if (amount < 1000)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(" Your balance is less than 1000, and u cannot make any withdrawals");

            }

            else

                Console.WriteLine("Balance is greater than Rs 1000 no need to panality");

        }

    }

    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome Mr.Sayeed");
            Console.WriteLine("Please select the type of account.\n1.Savings 2.Current 3.Exit");

            int ch; 
            ch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            switch (ch)
            {

                case 1:

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Initail Amount : ");

                    float amt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    sav_acc s = new sav_acc(amt);

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter deposit money : ");

                    float depos = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    s.getdeposit(depos);

                    s.display();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter withdrawl Amount");

                    float wamt = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    s.withdrawl(wamt);

                    s.display();

                    s.minbal();

                    s.display();

                    break;

                case 2:

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Initail Amount : ");

                    float am = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    cur_acc c = new cur_acc(am);

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter deposit money : ");

                    float depo = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    c.getdeposit(depo);

                    c.display();


                    Console.WriteLine("Enter withdrawl Amount");

                    float wam = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    c.withdrawl(wam);

                    c.display();

                    c.minbal();

                    c.display();

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for Using this applicaton");
                    return;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have made a wrong choice, Thank you...");
                    return;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: When an exception is thrown you can read the message of the exception as well as look at the stack trace of the exception. The should help you solve problems like this. If you still don't understand what the problem you should at least include that information in your question.

Comment: Is this a homework ? You should put a proper tag with it.

Answer (score 4):

`int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` requires you to enter a valid integer. If you just press return without entering a value, the method will throw an exception. Use `int.TryParse` instead.

```
int ch = 0; 
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), ch); 
switch (ch) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry was just fine, default case did it :-)

Comment: @Matten thanks. OP handles an invalid entry inside the default branch of the switch. That's why I skipped using the return value.